# Use str.contains in pandas with apply statement raises str object has not attribute str error

Tags: python, pandas

I thought it would be simply, but I'm stumbling on this for a while now.

I have a column containing several information but depending on some content I'd like to label ist with a category:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A1 zwd fill text", "B2 rest uninteresting", "A1 more random text"]})
```

I assumed that this would do the trick `df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Some Category" if x.col1.str.contains["A1"] else "Another Category", axis=1)`

but it just raises a `str object has not attribute str`. Is it impossible to use `str.contains` with `apply`?

Comment: You can omit the "str": `df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Some Category" if x.col1.contains["A1"] else "Another Category", axis=1)`

Comment: @John I tried that to before (sorry, didn't document in my question) and expected it to work, but it doesn't. I get an error `str object has no attribute 'contains'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for a optimal vectorized solution, we don't need custom `apply` methods for such trivial actions:

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('A1'), 'Some Category', 'Another Category')
           # np.where(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)
                    col1              col2
0       A1 zwd fill text     Some Category
1  B2 rest uninteresting  Another Category
2    A1 more random text     Some Category
```

---

Or purely pandas using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.contains('A1').map({True: 'Some Category', 
                                                False: 'Another Category'})

                    col1              col2
0       A1 zwd fill text     Some Category
1  B2 rest uninteresting  Another Category
2    A1 more random text     Some Category
```

---

**Timings**:

```
# create test dataframe of 900k rows
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A1 zwd fill text", "B2 rest uninteresting", "A1 more random text"]})
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*300000, ignore_index=True)
```

Solution 1: `np.where`:

```
%%timeit
np.where(dfbig['col1'].str.contains('A1'), 'Some Category', 'Another Category')

855 ms ± 3.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Solution 2: `Series.map`:

```
%%timeit
dfbig['col1'].str.contains('A1').map({True: 'Some Category', 
                                                False: 'Another Category'})

920 ms ± 15.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Solution 3: `apply`:

```
%%timeit
dfbig.apply(lambda x: "Some Category" if "A1" in x.col1 else "Another Category", axis=1)

28.5 s ± 446 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Conclusion**:
`numpy` is `~135 x` faster than `apply`

Comment: Works like a charm. Still I think a solution within pandas would be nice. And I wonder how much performance would differ.

Comment: See edit for pandas solution. Dont think speed would matter a lot for these two solutions. But these are definitely significantly faster than `apply`. @MichaelA

Comment: I tend to forget about the map function. But it's a fairly nice solution. Depending on my sparetime I'll try to measure to performance difference. Thanks again.

Comment: Just did the testing, see edit with conclusion. As expected, you should avoid using `apply` @MichaelA